# Set current date to UTCHours (0,0,0,0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, time

I am trying to get the current date in milliseconds and then I want to set it to UTCHours(0,0,0,0) but I am getting the error ".setUTCHours is not a function"
Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```js
const startDateInMS = new Date().getTime();
startDateInMS.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Don't use `getTime()`

Comment: `.getTime()` returns a number, the number of milliseconds since epoch. Thus, when you do startDateInMS.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);, you're really calling 274957285938.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0), which obviously throws an error because numbers don't have a `setUTCHours` method (274957285938 is just an example, obviously).

Comment: If I don't use getTime() the error goes away but the new Date() does not get set to the (0,0,0,0)

Comment: Edited my answer to include this question as well

Comment: `startDateInMS = new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer here:

```js
const startDateInMS = new Date()
startDateInMS.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log(startDateInMS)
```

> The setUTCHours() method sets the hour for a specified date according to universal time, and returns the number of milliseconds since  January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

So your code above will take `today` and reset it's time to the very beginning of the day.

Read more in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours).

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime so `getTime` only returns a number which does not come with the prototype of a date object.

And to your further question:

> If I don't use getTime() the error goes away but the new Date() does not get set to the (0,0,0,0)

It does. Check the console log.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now the concept. Do you know why am I getting this: This is the start Sat Feb 27 2021 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

Comment: Correct. You set the hours time of that date to 0... Are you expecting something else?

Comment: @EduardoUrbiola I added a bit more explanation into my answer

Comment: I was expecting to get 00:00:00 but I'm getting => 17:00:00

Comment: I'm getting `"2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z"` but I'm in Australia and this will change tomorrow ;)

Comment: Glad it works. Feel free to mark this the answer

Comment: When you `console.log(new Date())` you will get the current time in GMT or "Zulu", hence the "Z" at the end. However, if you use `console.log(new Date().toString())` you will get a time string with your _local_ date and time.